# How do I do historic continous integration with TeamCity?

Tags: svn, teamcity

I'm just getting started with CI, and I'm trying to create some metrics on my codebase. Is there a way to get TeamCity to run the build on each revision of my source in my SVN repository from the beginning? I can only find how to do builds from now on, not from r1.

I'd also like to know if you can build every revision, not just once every polling period.

Comment: I want to collect code metrics. I may have to just create a custom build runner to do it...I had just hoped there was an easy way to do it in TC.

Comment: Are the metrics worth it? I doubt. :)

Comment: When you say "code metrics", what precisely are you looking for? Build duration? Passing tests? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's a way to do it (not very straightforward but it could get it done at least):
If you for instance have your source code in subversion, you could use svnadmin dump in  a script to transfer revision by revision into a new repository.

If you do this with an appropriate interval and let teamcity listen to changes in the new repo teamcity should trigger a new build for each revision.

Thinking of it, another theoretical solution without dumps would be to:

1. Create a new copy of your build config (A)
2. Point it to a new empty folder in your repo (assuming svn here)
3. Create another build config (B) with a command line script that for each execution takes the next revision from of your existing repo and merge it into your new empty folder.
4. Add a change trigger to your build config copy A
5. Add a cron trigger to your build config B that runs at an appropriate interval.

I haven't tested any of these but hey, what could possibly go wrong? ;-)

Comment: I'm going to actually build a powershell script to do the work for this, but good job coming up with an answer that fits the requirements!